# Custom naming convention for AKS resources

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

Is there a way we can alter the resource names of the resources provisioned by AKS itself (screenshot below). I know I can change the node resource group name as per the documentation but cannot find any reference (or documentation) if we can change the AKS managed resource names. The resources for which I want to have custom naming specifically are:

1. Load balancer
2. AKS Virtual Machine Scale Set

[image]

Comment: Hello @Faizan, If my answer is helpful for you, you can Upvote and accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the resource names of the resources provisioned by AKS itself. Because it is managed by AKS only. you can give your own name of `node resource group` at the time of creation using IAC tool like `Terraform`, `Biceps` etc. But you can’t change the `node resource name` of AKS once created.

From Portal you can not assign your own name of `node_resource_group`

**Note** : [node_resource_group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster#node_resource_group) - (Optional) The name of the Resource Group where the Kubernetes Nodes should exist. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.

Azure requires that a new, non-existent Resource Group is used, as otherwise the provisioning of the Kubernetes Service will fail.

Please Refer these document : [azurerm_kubernetes_cluster | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/kubernetes_cluster#node_resource_group)

[Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters - Bicep & ARM template reference | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerservice/managedclusters?tabs=bicep)